# Getting solo GPU mining to work under Manjaro Linux OpenRC edition

Tags: monerod

new here and new to Monero.

I'm fairly new to the whole cryptocurrency thing, and I'd really like to try out mining Monero on my GPU. I'm running Manjaro Linux (a spin of Arch Linux) with OpenRC instead of systemd

My rig is an AMD 8350 Octocore running at 4 ghz, with an ATI Raedeon Sapphire 7770 HD GPU. 16 Gigs of RAM on the MB. Currently not overclocked. I'm also running the open source video drivers.

I am able to get the Monero GUI version up and running, but my hash rates make it useless, since it only mines on the CPUs. (this is monerod, which I installed from the Arch User Repository)

So, I'd like to find some way to mine using the GPU, as I think perhaps it might make it worthwhile. I'd also prefer to do it solo, although if that's completely impossible, I guess I could join a pool.

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to compile any of the miners that are supposed to work on this set up. I always end up getting one or another error, usually with some file not being found by the compiler. I've tried sgminer from the Arch Repositories and I get an error that there's a conflict with a package needed by ImageMagick that is an OpenRC version.  it has a dependency issue with ocl-icd which breaks the dependency for opencl-icd-loader for imagemagick... I don't know any way to get around this, as I need ImageMagick for other things.

When I try to build Wolf's Miner I get missing files in the make command. And I also cannot get Monero-stratum to build (I have seen some posts here that suggest stratum as a method of solo mining) There are etherium versions of stratum in the Arch Repos, so I was sort of wondering if I could use one of those instead? And how wpould one set up eth-stratum to work with monero, and Wolf's miner (if possible)

What would be best would be to find that Monerod had been updated to use the GPU, but I'm wondering if there is even any plan by anyone to do that?

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions that would help out a complete newb? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you insist on "Manjaro Linux" ?